# Multiple Google Maps in 1 page with cfmap

Tags: coldfusion

How can multiple maps be rendered in the same page with cfmap?

Currently only the first map can render.

This is what I have:

```
<cfmap name="gmap01" 
    centerlatitude="#trlat#" 
    centerlongitude="#trlong#" 
    doubleclickzoom="true" 
    overview="true" 
    scrollwheelzoom="true" 
    showscale="true" 
    tip="My Map" 
    zoomlevel="13"
    typecontrol="basic"
    height="300"
    width ="400"/>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add multiple maps, just add another cfmap tag with a different name attribute. The following code works just fine on my 9.0.1 system.

```
<cfmap name="gmap01"
    doubleclickzoom="true"
    overview="true"
    scrollwheelzoom="true"
    showscale="true"
    tip="My Map"
    zoomlevel="13"
    typecontrol="basic"
    height="300"
    width ="400"
    centeraddress="Austin, TX"
/>
<cfmap name="gmap02"
    doubleclickzoom="true"
    overview="true"
    scrollwheelzoom="true"
    showscale="true"
    tip="My Map"
    zoomlevel="13"
    typecontrol="basic"
    height="300"
    centeraddress="Amarillo, TX"
    width ="400"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should answer your questions, syntax is simple:

http://coldfusionexamples.com/2010/11/03/creating-multiple-markers-on-a-map-using-the-cfmapitem-tag-in-coldfusion-9/